# Perl one-liner substitution without further expansion of a shell variable?

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I have a script to replace a specific email address in various files. The replacement address is the first parameter to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pi -e s/'name\@domain\.org'/$1/ file-list
```

This doesn't work, as the `@` character in `$1` is substituted by perl. Is there a straightforward fix for this? Running the script as `subst foo\@bar.com`, `subst foo\\@bar.com`, `subst "foo@bar.com"`, and so on, doesn't work. Is there a sed script that could handle this more easily?

Comment: `perl -spe 's/name@domain\.org/$replace/' -- -replace="$1" file-list`

Comment: The way you posted it, `$1` is substituted by bash, because it is outside the single quotes.

Comment: Unless partial matches are allowed, e.g. `lastname@domain.org`, you might wish to adjust for that. Firstly by determining how email addresses are delimited in your files. It sort of looks like maybe they are surrounded by single quotes (or you may just be confused in how Perl one-liners work). If so, that would work. Also, you can access shell variables inside Perl via the `%ENV` hash, e.g. `perl -i -pe's/.../$ENV{1}/g' file-list`

Comment: @TLP To access a shell variable via Perl's `%ENV` has, you must export the variable in the shell environment first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of expanding a shell variable directly in the perl code you can pass it as an argument by setting the `s` switch:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

perl -i -spe 's/name\@domain\.org/$replacement/' -- -replacement="$1" file1.txt file2.txt
```

In perl's `s///`, without the use of `e` or `ee` modifiers, variables in the replacement part are treated as literals so you don't need to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but needs you to pass the new mail address to the script with the `@` character preceded by `\\`:

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pi -e "s/name\@domain.org/$1/" file-list
```

If the script is `subst`, run as:

```
subst newname\\@example.com
```

This is a better alternative, which uses `sed` to carry out the escaping:

```
#!/bin/bash
ADR="$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/@/\\\@/')"
perl -pi -e "s/name\@domain.org/$ADR/" file-list
```

Of course, in this case it's probably better to use `sed` to do the whole thing.